# No route matches [GET] "/contato"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'd like to do a contact form, but I'm get a routing error.

```
No route matches [GET] "/contato"
```

My view (contato.html.erb):

```
<%= form_tag(contato_path, method: :post) %>            

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <%= text_field_tag 'name', placeholder: "Name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <%= submit_tag 'Send' %>    
    </div>

<% end %>
```

My controller (pages_controller.erb):

class PagesController < ApplicationController

```
  def home
    .....
  end

  def search
   .....
  end

  def contato
    .....
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
post '/contato' => 'pages#contato'
```

Rake routes:

```
contato_path    POST    /contato(.:format)  pages#contato
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to display the form in `contato.html.erb` for which there's no `GET` request defined. Don't use the same action for both `GET` and `POST` requests.

Create a new action to display the form

```
def new
  #renders new.html.erb
end
```

Add the following route to your `routes.rb`

```
get '/new' => 'pages#new'
```

Move the form to `new.html.erb` and then process the form in `contato` action